# How to transform 1D Array to 2D Array with duplication

Tags: python, numpy

Say I have a 1-dimensional numpy array with shape (5,):

```
a = np.array(range(0,5))
```

And I want to transform it two a 2-dimensional array by duplicating the array above 3 times, so that the shape will be (5,3), for example:

```
array([[0,1,2,3,4],
      [0,1,2,3,4],
      [0,1,2,3,4]])
```

How would I do that? I know that with lists, you can use list.copy() to create a copy, but I don't want to convert my array to a list first.

Comment: numpy has a `vstack` function that will do what you're after

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With [`numpy.tile`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html).

```
>>> a = np.arange(5)
>>> np.tile(a, (3, 1))
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]])
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `*` operator on list.

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array(3*[range(0,5)])
```